# Using geometry points to get data in order to plot heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, points

Excuse me if the title is confusing, English is not my main language, I'll try to explain myself as best as possible, also, I'm not great graphing, I'm learning.

My code plots points on a shapefile representation using Point from geometry and geopandas. I'd like to create a heatmap with the data I have. Some research has showed me that in order to do so I'd need to have a value that would represent the size of the ''heat'', could I create such data column using the points I already have, so, for example, if there's a lot of points at xy area at the plot, then the value for that point would represent small and bright colored heat?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import descartes
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

street_map = gpd.read_file('shape_files/Street_Network_Database_(SND).shp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))

street_map.plot(ax=ax, color="grey", alpha=0.3)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
crs = {"init":"epsg:4326"}

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df["longitude"], df["latitude"])]

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

geo_df.plot(ax = ax, markersize = 10, color = "blue", marker = "o", label = "POI")
```

Here's the results of this code:

[image]

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: First of all, you need to decide how you will cluster your points to determine regions and the "heat" of each region.  Then you need to research how to create heat maps with Matplotlib.  See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a kernel density estimation in the geoplot package.

Check out the syntax here: [geoplot.kdeplot](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html#kdeplot)

And the geopandas example on the bottom of the page: [Plotting with Geoplot and GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_with_geoplot.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a heatmap easily with [`folium`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html?highlight=heatmap#folium.plugins.HeatMap) from only a list of lists of latitudes and longitudes:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

seattle_map = folium.Map(location=[47.6062, 122.3321], zoom_start = 13) 

heatmap_data = list(map(list, zip(df['latitude'], df['longitude'])))

HeatMap(heatmap_data).add_to(seattle_map)

seattle_map
```

Comment: I don't understand how Folium works. What are you representing with seattle_map? Can I use my street_map variable somehow? (I've tried so but just got 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'add_child' error)

Comment: `folium` uses [`leaflet`](https://leafletjs.com/) to create a dynamic map, by default from OpenStreetMap. This is what `folium.Map` does (using a random location I picked for Seattle). You can, however, customize the look using [tiles](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html). Folium clusters the points into a heatmap, depending on the zoom level. You can take a look at [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Heatmap.ipynb) example. And don't create `heatmap_data` from your `geo_df`, but from the `df` as in my example.